# Google Site Verification API

Tags: dotnetopenauth, google-search-console, http-status-code-503, google-site-verification-api

I am trying to develop Google site verification system using ASP.Net. Also using the Google explorer (https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/webResource/insert) to test the request method such as JSON and HTTP request format.

This is what I am sending to the Google.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/siteVerification/v1/webResource?verificationMethod=site&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "id": "myid",
 "owners": [
  "development@gmail.com"
 ],
 "site": {
  "type": "site",
  "identifier": "http://www.example.net/"
 }
}
```

I am getting following response from the Google.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

>

```
IAuthorizationState authorization;        
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (googleClient != null)
        {                                
            if (IsPostBack)
            {                    
                authorization = googleClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();
                if (authorization != null)
                {
                    this.AccessToken = authorization.AccessToken;

                }
                else if (this.AccessToken == null)
                {
                    googleClient.RequestUserAuthorization(scope: new[] { GoogleClient.Scopes.WebMaster.SiteVerification });
                }
            }                               
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (authorization != null)
          {
              IOWebMasterInsertGraph webMasterInsertGraph = googleClient.RequestForVerification(authorization);               

          }
    }

public IOWebMasterInsertGraph RequestForVerification(IAuthorizationState authState)
        {
            if ((authState != null) && (authState.AccessToken != null))
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/siteVerification/v1/webResource?verificationMethod=site");


                string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/GoogleInsert.json");

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                FileStream fileStreem = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[fileStreem.Length];
                fileStreem.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fileStreem.Length);
                ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)fileStreem.Length);

                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentLength = ms.Length;
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    ms.CopyTo(requestStream);
                } 

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                if (response != null)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        //return GoogleGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);
                        return WebMasterInsertGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Can you please attach your code? Do you use the .NET client library (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/)?

Comment: I was trying to use Google .Net client library. But there ware so many version in-compatibility. I am using DotNetOpenOauth. But I am getting above error with https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/webResource/insert. Anyway I will attache my coding too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself.

The following has to be sent to the GoogleApi without the **id** in JSON. The **verificationMethos** has to be one you selected when getting token.

```
    POST /siteVerification/v1/webResource?verificationMethod=file HTTP/1.1 Host: www.googleapis.com 
    Content-length: 138 
    Content-type: application/json 
    Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 

    {   
       "owners": [
            "sample@gmail.com"   ],     
       "site": {
            "identifier": "http://test.sample.com/",
            "type": "SITE"   } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [Google .NET client library for Site verification](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Site_Verification_API)?
You even have a [sample code](http://samples.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/SiteVerification.VerifySite/README.html) for that.
Try it out...

Comment: I have tried. But ended up with lot of missing assembly references and version incompatibilities.